# Live audio peak detection from a microphone

Tags: audio, detection

I need to detect peaks in a live audio from a pickup microphone and output the exact time to milliseconds or preferably nanoseconds of the peak in a .txt file.

I have been looking at two possible solutions. The first one was to set up a shell script in linux to record audio increments of 5 seconds via the nohup function and then analyze them in matlab, but the problem here is that the endings and the beginnings of the recorded files are not exactly 5 seconds apart. There is a delay of 50-150 milliseconds when a new file starts recording.

The second option was to do something similar to what they use for clap light switches, but I have no idea how I would extract the exact time from that. And I also don't know if that would work with a pickup microphone or does it just work with a sound sensor (for Arduino...) like it is shown here.http://en.code-bude.net/2014/12/08/how-to-build-a-clap-switch-using-arduino/

I want to know if there is a better solution out there. Can I do this in C++ or java, perhaps? Remember, I need to output the exact time in milli- or nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get accurate timing information you'll need to count samples and then compute the time from the beginning of the recording from that.

First you need to decide on one of the many audio capture playback APIs that are available. You haven't mentioned which platform you're on but if you're on linux you could look at ALSA,Jack,OSS,SDL just to name a few. Once you to the point where you are able to configure the capture device and start receiving samples then the method is going to be similar for each one. You will get some kind of function callback with the received samples and will need to scan the samples for peaks and compute the times, etc...

Here is an example of what a callback *might* look like. Keep in mind that the API you choose will have its own subtleties and you'll likely need to convert from byte arrays to double, etc...  The `time` will be `double` precision value with an accuracy of 1/SAMPLERATE.

```
 int sampleCount = 0;
 void BufferCallback(double* samples, int numSamples)
 {
     for (int i = 0 ; i < numSamples ; i++)
     {
         if (abs(samples[i]) > threshold)
         {
             // exceeded peak threshold, record the time
             double time = sampleCount / (double)SampleRate;
         }
         sampleCount++;
     }
 }
```